# angular-ui tab renders anchor tag without href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using AngularUI tabs as seen in the following sample code below and in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlbrObH4sBlyUFZO2tZh?p=preview).

http://plnkr.co/edit/YlbrObH4sBlyUFZO2tZh?p=preview

```
    <tabset class="tabbable tabbable-custom tabbable-full-width">
    <tab class="active" heading="Latest Customers" href="javascript:;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Div1">
            Pane 1
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Feeds" href="javascript:;">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Div2" href="javascript:;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Div3">
               Pane 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

As you can see in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlbrObH4sBlyUFZO2tZh?p=preview), when the mouse hovers over the "tab", the cursor does not change to your typical pointing finger.  The anchor tag that angularui is rendering does not have a href value on it, therefore, it is considered invalid html.  if i manually add href="javascript:;" , the cursor works like i want it.

My question is, how can i tell the directive to add a href to the anchor tag?  any advice?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a style that targets the tabs:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just write:

```
<tabset 
       class="tabbable tabbable-custom tabbable-full-width"
       style="cursor: pointer;"
 >
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmh this is weird, I too am using angular-ui tabs in my project. I copied and pasted the exact code you provided and it works just fine.

(see bottom of http://wiredbeast.com/coolframework/docs.html#/activity) 
I might remove it later so look quick.

So my guess is that it's something wrong with your bootstrap css. I'm using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js, bootstrap.js/css v3.0.0, and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js for angular